# 4 light switches powered by 1 hot wire

Tags: electrical

In my master bathroom are 4 light switches:

- 1 dimmer for dimmable overhead LEDS
- 1 toggle for mirror LEDs
- 1 toggle for runner LEDs
- 1 timer switch for light/fan exhaust for shower

I recently replaced these switches. Unlike every other circuit in my house (which have 1 hot per light switch), this 4 gang had the following:

- 1 hot wire
- 6 return / pole wires
- 6 neutrals
- 6 grounds

I wired it all up and it's working (daisy chained the grounds, split the hot into 4, and tied together 3 of the returns with a wire nut (which is how it was done by electrician before I replaced it).

*I did wire the hot differently than the electrician however*. The electrician daisy-chained the hot across the 4 lights; I instead used a wire nut to split the 1 hot into 4 hots which I ran to each of the 4 light switches. All the rest of the circuit is fine (neutrals are tied off and unused).

Is this safe and/or OK? Any issues to look out for aside of loose wires? All wire nuts are located in the 4 gang box, and other than the grounds which I daisy chained, there are never 2 wires on a single fastener screw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using a wirenut to connect the hot to 4 pigtails is perfectly fine. Wirenuts are designed to carry the full current of the connected wires. Just make sure all of the wires are nice and snug.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can loop the hot to all the switches it just makes mounting them a bit tougher, but it is fine to do this.

Comment: I know that connections create heat to some degree. Is there no concern of 1 hot becoming 4 and the heat generated at the wire nut?